# Переменная, содержащая большой код HTML

Tags: php

Можно ли в `$na_primer = "` сюда вставить HTML теги. Естественно, все теги закрывать одинарными кавычками `''`. К примеру, вот такая конструкция:

`<?php $star = "сюда вставить таблицу, которую разбить на столбики и строчки, заполнив последние некой информацией... и так же php кодом (переменными, ссылками, стилями, короче чем в голову прийдет, тем и забить - соблюдая синтаксис конечно. "'" "'")";`

Будет ли в таком случае работать `$`? Воспримет ли такое интерпретатор PHP?

Answer (score 7):

Хороший вопрос. Подобный отнял у меня день жизни)
Я покажу как можно осуществить. К примеру у меня есть главная страничка и почти вся она состоит из php кода. Задача: вставить HTML в php код, но в HTML также есть php код.
Сделал так:

**1 файл: (while.php)**

```
<?php
echo '<table><tr>';
echo '<td style=" width:200px;">';
echo "<p><img src=$img></p>"."".$go."<br>".$reg."<br>".$row; //Вот и переменные
echo '</td>';   
echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

**2 файл(главная страница):**

```
<?php

//Так мы подключили while.php (необходимо подключить именно так)
    ob_start();
include 'while.php';
$include = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//Далее конструкция print <<<HERE HERE; Запомните что перед и после этих тегов не должно быть даже пробелов.

print <<<HERE

<table  height="2000px" background="stripe.png" width="1000px" border="1"  cellspacing="1" style=" margin-bottom:35px; position: absolute; top:144px; left:450px;" >

<tr>

<td background="Stopka.jpg" valign="top" width="225px">
</td>

<td>
 <h3 style=" padding-left:35px; padding-top:20px;">Главная страница</h3>
 <hr style=" position:absolute; left:260px; top:40px" width=700px>
 <br>
 <p style=" padding-left:100px">{$include}</p> //Вот так мы вставили 1-ой переменной наш php код с переменными)

</td>
</tr>
</table>

HERE;

?>
```

Comment: Промучившись весь день, я сделал по практически такой же схеме!:)
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 6):

Лучше всего делать так, ИМХО. Я раньше постоянно так поступал:

```
$html = <<<HERE
    // Тут любой код HTML с любыми ковычками
HERE;
echo $html;
```

И это всегда прекрасно отрабатывало.

Comment: А $html это глобальная переменная? 
Я хочу создать файл с раширением *.dat и в него поместить html код. 
Допустим по вашей схеме 
$html = <<<HERE
    // Тут любой код HTML с любыми ковычками
    HERE;
echo $html;

потом $html вставить в нужные мне страницы.
И в нужных страницах проинклюдить файл *.dat
Получится?

Comment: тогда лучше прочитайте про шаблоны и ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller

Comment: Файлик .php придется сделать, а не .dat. И оградить его тэгами:

    <?php ?>

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за совет!

Comment: перед последним HERE; не должно быть никаких символов. За это хередок ненавижу: нарушает ступеньки кода.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы спрашиваете, будет ли работать  следующим образом

```
$a="Привет";
$b="$a Вася";
echo $b;
```

выведет 'Привет Вася'

То да - будет работать. Единственно, что по мне лучше делать вот так: `echo $a. 'Вася';`

Comment: Нет, я не это имел ввиду. Представим у нас есть некая переменная $noob = "тут её значение";
Значением $noob является "<table><tr><td> тут куча тегов, текста, картинок, и всего остального чего хотите. Только все в одинарных кавычках, так как значение переменной в двойных кавычках</td></tr></table>" Будет ли переменная работать, если скажем я её выложу на главную страничку?

Comment: $noob="<table><tr><td class='myclas'>" - отработает прекрасно
$noob="<table><tr><td class='$myclass'>" - отработает но не така как вы ждете, то есть переменную $myclass интерпретатор не воспримет а выведет просто как строку $myclass

Comment: А зачем вы из myclass сделали переменную? Этож просто класс из файла CSS =))

Или это просто как вариант не отработки ссылок в нутри тега HTML?

Comment: я вам привел пример того, как интерпретатор обработает строку. Я просто не совсем понял что вы именно хотите спросить

Comment: Все, я понял. Спасибо за толковые ответы. 
А имел я ввиду то, что бы в значение переменной в место допустим "Вася" вставить HTML код. Что из этого выедет, для примера взял таблицу с неким содержимым...

Comment: $myClass - просто переменная. Она может быть равна чему угодно: 

    $myClass = 'myClass';
    $myClass = "myClass";

Она может быть даже классом c методом __tostring. Php занимается тем чтобы определить что ему нужно вывести вместо этой переменной (т.е. передать на обработку браузеру). PHP может вывести вместо нее Notice, что данная переменная не была определена ранее, а может и Fatal Error быть и ничего больше не вывести. Повторяю: всем этим занимается PHP. Как только PHP сделал свою работу на сервере, сервер возвращает браузеру клиента HTML код, и далее уже браузер отображает код.

Comment: P.S. Спасибо много, незабывайте отмечать правильные ответы ;-)

Comment: Код:

    $noob= "<table><tr><td class='$myclass'>";
    echo $noob;

Отработает самым прекрасным образом. И переменную $myclass он тоже выведет, если она известна.
А вот код:

    $noob= '<table><tr><td class=\'$myclass\'>';
    // или: $noob= '<table><tr><td class="$myclass">';
    echo $noob;

Выведет: 
    <table><tr><td class='$myclass'>

Переменную $myclass php не воспримет в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

лучше шаблонами.
в шаблонах выставьте нужные псевдо-тэги для вашей обработки.
типа:

```
<html><body><p> сегодняшняя дата:</p> {{DATE}} </body></html>
```

в php обработчике читаете файл шаблона (с текстом выше), и обрабатываете его, заменяя {{DATE}}  на date("d-m-Y"). 
например:

```
$T = file_get_contents('файл шаблона');
$T = str_replace('{{DATE}}',date("d-m-Y"),$T);
// еще какие-то действия с текстом шаблона.
echo $T;
```

и потом выводите.
это самый простой пример шаблонизации.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробуем!
P.S. Мне кажется что это лучший сайт, на котором можно получить исчерпывающий и понятный ответ!
Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 0):

Вам сюда: [PHP: Строки - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Файл: html.php

```
<? $text = 'Переменная'; ?>
<div>
    <h1><? echo $text; ?></h1> 
</div>
```

Главная страница:

```
<? 
function HTML() { 
    return include("html.php"); 
} 
?>
HTML();
```